# How to convert date in mysql date formate to javascript date formate in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, reactjs

I have an array of objects which I have retrieved from mysql database they have date objects which are in mysql date formate, I want to convert them into javascript Date() objects

I tried to do this

```
Expenses = Expenses.map((expense) =>{return  Date.parse(expense.date)})
```

and

```
Expense = Expenses.map((expense) =>{return {...expense, date : new Date(expense.date)};})}
```

but this does not works

In the end I am trying to filter the dates using js date object

```
date = new Date("2020-07-10T00:00:00");

Expenses = Expenses.filter(expense => expense.date > date );
```

But the dates do not converts into js Date objects

Comment: Looks like you refering to the Java programming language, not JavaScript. If so, by writing "date objects which are in mysql date formate" - you mean String?

Comment: yes I am working with javascript in reactjs environment. And yes they came from mysql database when I retrived them in string fomate for example "2022-11-06T19:29:29.000+00:00" this is the formate they came in. I can convert them into a normal formate using 'moment' but I cannot convert them into actual javascript date objects